# Code duplication - Symfony2

Tags: symfony, code-duplication

I'm using Symfony2 and Doctrine and I have several lines duplicated in almost all of the methods of my controller.

Here they are:

```
$this->expense = $this->expenseRepository->findByExpenseId($id);

    if(!$this->expense){
        echo 'There is no expense with such id...';
        //redirect to error page
    } else {
        return $this->expense = $this->expense[0];
    }
```

I couldn't think a better way to avoid it than this:

```
private function findExpense($id)
{
    $this->expense = $this->expenseRepository->findByExpenseId($id);

    if(!$this->expense){
        return $this->redirect .... ;
    } else {
        return $this->expense = $this->expense[0];
    }
}
```

and then in each method something like this :

```
    $expense = $this->findExpense($id);        
    if (!$expense) {
        return $expense;
    }
```

but I'm not quite sure it's ok. Can you please give me some ideas how to improve this and get rid of the duplicated code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move that code into a [service](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/service_container.html). Like that you can access your method like this:

```
$expense = $this->get('expenseFinder')->findExpense($id);
```

The advantage over your current method is that all your code logic would be stored in one single file. So maintaining it will be easier. Also you should *never* use the `echo` method inside your `Controllers`. Render an appropriate [template](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html) instead or throw an exception. For your case the `HttpNotFoundException` seems to be the right choice.

```
if(!$this->expense){
    throw new HttpNotFoundException();
} else {
    return $this->expense = $this->expense[0];
}
```

---

Create a `expenseFinder.php` in `src/[Your Company]/[Your Bundle]/Util`.

```
class expenseFinder {

    protected $em;


    public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function findExpense($id) {
        // your logic here...
    }

}
```

And register your service in the `app/config/config.yml`

```
services:
    expenseFinder:
        class: [Your Company]\[Your Bundle]\expenseFinder
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

Now you can call it as described in the beginning of my post.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I can't userdstand how exactly to use this approach :( - how to give the id as parameter to the service (if I have to give it at all)? And there are 1-2 methods which don't need this - what will happen with the id then? And what exactly should I have in the service's class :( Sorry for the questions and thank you very much once again. :)